# Are there any ways to add token to the header when I want to submit the form in posting method?

Tags: javascript

what I want to do is to add the token to request in the submmiting form. How can I achieve this? This is my code,the :action comes from 'vue-bind'.

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" :action="mainUrl+'/nameList'">
                    <ol>
                        <li><a href="http://120.55.113.9:8080/prizesearch-main/file/NameList.xls">download the files</a></li>
                        <li><input type="file" @change="jsReadFiles" :files="files" ref="inputfile" name="nameListFile"></li>
                        <li><input type="submit" value="upload the files"></li>
                    </ol>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [jQuery's](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) beforeSend callback to add an HTTP header with the authentication information:

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", token);
},
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-with-jquery-and-ajax) for more info.

Comment: Acutally, I am not quiet familiar with JQuery. Is there a way to achieve this just in JS? I don't know how to manipulate the request in the form. Do I have to prevent the submit and construct my own request?

Comment: Create a js function and pass relevant arguments when the submit button is pressed. Create the request inside your js function. You can append the request like  `req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', token );`